# Проблема удаления динамического массива

Tags: c++11, динамические-массивы

Столкнулся с проблемой, визуалка мне выдает ошибку при удалении динамического массива.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
void fast_sort(unsigned* begin, unsigned* end) {
    unsigned r = 255;
    unsigned raz = 8;
    int t = 1;
    unsigned* d;
    d = new unsigned[end - begin]();
    for (int i = 0; i < end - begin; i++) {
        d[i] = *(begin + i);
    }
    unsigned* a;
    a = new unsigned[end - begin]();
    while ((raz <= sizeof(unsigned) * 8) && (t)) {
        t = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int f = 0;
        int b[256] = { 0 }, c[256] = { 0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < end - begin; i++) {
            b[((d[i] >> (raz - 8)) & (r))]++;
            a[i] = d[i];
        }
        c[0] = b[0];
        bool temp = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
            c[i] = c[i - 1] + b[i - 1];
            if (b[i]) {
                t++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < end - begin; i++) {
            f = ((a[i] >> (raz - 8)) & (r));
            x = c[f];
            d[x] = a[i];
            c[f]++;
        }
        raz += 8;
    }
    delete[] a;
    for (int i = 0; i < end - begin; i++) {
        *(begin + i) = d[i];
    }
    delete[] d;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned arr[1000];
    int razmer = rand() % 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < razmer; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
    fast_sort(arr, arr + razmer);
}
```

Comment: Есть смысл привести текст сообщения и точку, где возникает проблема - это увеличит число желающих заняться Вашей проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем несколько проверок:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < end - begin; i++) {
        assert(((d[i] >> (raz - 8)) & (r)) < 256);
        b[((d[i] >> (raz - 8)) & (r))]++;
...

    for (int i = 0; i < end - begin; i++) {
        f = ((a[i] >> (raz - 8)) & (r));
        assert(f < 256);
        x = c[f];
        assert(x < (end-begin));
        d[x] = a[i];
```

Запускаем - и вуаля:

```
Assertion failed: x < (end-begin), file ...\test.cpp, line 39
```

Выход за пределы выделенной памяти. Вот и причина ваших слетов.

Если не секрет - что мешало вам использовать если не `assert`, то хотя бы отладочный вывод? Не спрашиваю уж об отладчике...

Comment: Спасибо, мешала неопытность в программировании, все же не так давно начал этим заниматься, и до этого получалось, а тут прямо не понимал в чем ошибка.

Comment: Лучше, конечно, изучать отладчик. Но если нет - хотя бы вставлять отладочный вывод и смотреть, не получается ли ерунда. Не скажу о точных %%, но, думаю, 20% времени на написание кода и 80% на отладку - соотношение более-менее правдивое :)